# Outlook archive function from IMAP folder to local folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap

I have a 1GB mailbox, now my mail client downloads messages to local folders via POP because 1GB is not enought to leave them online.

Now I would like to share the mailbox with another computer, therefore I supposed to switch to IMAP protocol but I have to manage the mailbox limited size. I can accept to share messages of a limited period, for example last 6 months, but I need that at least one computer has access to all message archive.

Can "archive" function of Outlook automatically move old messages from online IMAP mailbox to local folder?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Outlook Auto-Archive function works with IMAP account, it can automatically move old messages to local archive PST file.